# Django registration | change behaviour

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-1.9

After succesfully registering, the user is redirected to the template 'registration_done.html'.

Is there any way of changing this behaviour to redirecting the user to the registration page and displaying a message?

I tried these code below also tried different ways to change it but have different types of errors in different cases.

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^register/$',
        views.register,
        {
            'success_url': '/accounts/register/?success=true'
        },
        name='register'),
```

**view.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            success = request.GET.get('success', None)
            return render(request, {'new_user': new_user, 'success': success})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

**registration.html**:

```
{% if success %}
      <p>{% trans 'Successfull registration!' %}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Whats wrong I did?!

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'success_url'
[18/Aug/2016 14:17:55] "GET /en/account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59886
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: With code which you can see in the post I have this error `TypeError at /account/register/
register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'success_url'` but is there any good ways to make my task?! How do you think?!

Comment: here is what a stack trace looks like https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b26cf0dfe73d3bbf2e74fcae277c0b667930366f/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f326749644f4e352e706e67

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass the kwarg `success_url` to your function `register`

Your function `register(request)` only accepts one argument: 'request'.

So you can accept a second argument, say success_url, like so

```
def register(request, success_url):
    ...
```

But there is no point doing that if success_url is a constant. In that case, just define it your register function

```
def register(request): 
    success_url = 'foo'
```

Another point here is that you want to [reverse that url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), rather than hard code it.

Also I'm not sure why you would want to use this:

```
success = request.GET.get('success', None)
```

Any user could submit their own success variable in the GET request. Are you expecting this from a form? Looks like a security vulnerability if the user can just say that the were successful in request.GET.

Right now you aren't actually rendering a template on success anyway because you are missing a template name/path from your first `render` call.

So either add a template or redirect them to another page.

Comment: Well it`s sad of course. I tried to redirect to registration page after successful register but form disappeared however I have message. Seems strange.

Comment: how did you try to redirect?

Comment: I tried with this one `return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user, 'success': success})`

Comment: that's not a redirect. You are rendering a different form form the same view. Try creating a new view ... e.g. ```def registration_success(request)``` then instead of returning render, just redirect e.g. ```return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registration_success'))```

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek that will reduce view coupling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)